# How to write xpath to checkAddResult value

Tags: xpath, soapui

How to write XPath to get AddResult text value

```
  <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" 
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
      xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
     <soap:Body>
       <AddResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
         <AddResult>128</AddResult>
       </AddResponse>
     </soap:Body>
  </soap:Envelope>
```

I tried below but not getting the desired result

```
declare namespace soap='http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope';
/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/AddResponse/AddResult/text()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Found Answeer:**

I should create another namespace with url same as in response xml and use in xpath,below is the answer

```
declare namespace soap='http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope';
declare namespace xmlns='http://tempuri.org/';
/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/xmlns:AddResponse/xmlns:AddResult/text()
```

Comment: What happens when you use just `//AddResult/text()`?

Comment: @JackFleeting we will get an error as Missing content for xpath

Comment: For reading data, you can just use wildcard any namespace: `//*:AddResponse/*:AddResult`.